# Can't type accented characters in Sublime Text 3 (Ubuntu 14.10)

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext, sublimetext3

For some reason I'm unable to type accented characters like á å, ä in Sublime Text 3.
Instead I only get the following output ´a °a, ¨a. The hat symbols get typed when I press their key instead of allowing me to type an accented character, I'm using an icelandic keyboard by the way.

Sublime text build 3065, Ubuntu 64 bit. Running on Ubuntu 14.10.

This issue doesn't show up for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a way to fix this, in Sublime Text go to **Preferences > Key Bindings - User**, add the code below to the file that opens `Default (Linux).sublime-keymap` and save it.

Note that this is a hacky fix and may not contain all accented letters you need/want, in that case you could easily add those missing letters. Also note that this fix doesn't attack the root of the problem which I think has something to do with Ubuntu 14.10.

```
[
    // missing accented characters fix for ubuntu 14.10

    // a, [á, å, ä]
    { "keys": ["´","a"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "á"}},
    { "keys": ["°","a"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "å"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","a"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ä"}},

    // A, [Á, Å, Ä]
    { "keys": ["´","A"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Á"}},
    { "keys": ["°","A"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Å"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","A"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ä"}},

    // e, [é, ë]
    { "keys": ["´","e"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "é"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","e"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ë"}},

    // E, [É, Ë]
    { "keys": ["´","E"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "É"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","E"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ë"}},

    // i, [í, ï]
    { "keys": ["´","i"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "í"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","i"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ï"}},

    // I, [Í, Ï]
    { "keys": ["´","I"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Í"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","I"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ï"}},

    // o, [ó, ö]
    { "keys": ["´","o"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ó"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","o"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ö"}},

    // O, [Ó, Ö]
    { "keys": ["´","O"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ó"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","O"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ö"}},

    // u, [ú, ů, ü]
    { "keys": ["´","u"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ú"}},
    { "keys": ["°","u"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ů"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","u"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ü"}},

    // U, [Ú, Ů, Ü]
    { "keys": ["´","U"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ú"}},
    { "keys": ["°","U"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ů"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","U"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ü"}},

    // y, [ý, ÿ]
    { "keys": ["´","y"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ý"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","y"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ÿ"}},

    // Y, [Ý, Ÿ]
    { "keys": ["´","Y"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ý"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","Y"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ÿ"}}
]
```

Comment: I was experienced the same problem after upgrade to 14.10. Solved by removing and re-added the keymap EN_US international with dead keys. It was automatically changed to EN_US international AltGr Unicode combining, that was incorrect.

Comment: Cool, if you add an answer with more details on how you fixed this issue (baby steps for the dumb) without the above hack I'll try it out, and if it works I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: Done. I hope it can help you and others. But, sorry if is not the same problem.

Answer (score 22):

I have some complements for those who use a ABNT2 Keyboard, works fine with Brazilian folks.

In **Preferences > Key Bindings - User**, add the following snippet:

```
[
    // missing accented characters fix for ubuntu 14.10

    // a, [á, à, ã, â, å, ä]
    { "keys": ["´","a"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "á"}},
    { "keys": ["`","a"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "à"}},
    { "keys": ["~","a"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ã"}},
    { "keys": ["^","a"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "â"}},
    { "keys": ["°","a"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "å"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","a"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ä"}},

    // A, [Á, À, Ã, Â, Å, Ä]
    { "keys": ["´","A"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Á"}},
    { "keys": ["`","A"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "À"}},
    { "keys": ["~","A"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ã"}},
    { "keys": ["^","A"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Â"}},
    { "keys": ["°","A"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Å"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","A"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ä"}},

    // e, [é, è, ê, ẽ, ë]
    { "keys": ["´","e"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "é"}},
    { "keys": ["`","e"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "è"}},
    { "keys": ["^","e"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ê"}},
    { "keys": ["~","e"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ẽ"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","e"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ë"}},

    // E, [É, È, Ê, Ẽ, Ë]
    { "keys": ["´","E"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "É"}},
    { "keys": ["`","E"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "È"}},
    { "keys": ["^","E"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ê"}},
    { "keys": ["~","E"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ẽ"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","E"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ë"}},

    // i, [ì, í, ï]
    { "keys": ["`","i"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ì"}},
    { "keys": ["´","i"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "í"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","i"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ï"}},

    // I, [Ì, Í, Ï]
    { "keys": ["`","I"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ì"}},
    { "keys": ["´","I"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Í"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","I"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ï"}},

    // o, [ó, õ, ô, ö]
    { "keys": ["´","o"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ó"}},
    { "keys": ["~","o"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "õ"}},
    { "keys": ["^","o"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ô"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","o"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ö"}},

    // O, [Ó, Õ, Ô, Ö]
    { "keys": ["´","O"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ó"}},
    { "keys": ["~","O"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Õ"}},
    { "keys": ["^","O"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ô"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","O"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ö"}},

    // u, [ú, ů, ü]
    { "keys": ["´","u"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ú"}},
    { "keys": ["°","u"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ů"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","u"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ü"}},

    // U, [Ú, Ů, Ü]
    { "keys": ["´","U"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ú"}},
    { "keys": ["°","U"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ů"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","U"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ü"}},

    // y, [ý, ÿ]
    { "keys": ["´","y"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ý"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","y"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ÿ"}},

    // Y, [Ý, Ÿ]
    { "keys": ["´","Y"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ý"}},
    { "keys": ["¨","Y"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ÿ"}}
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Sublime Text is an awesome editor, and XCompose is very convenient for quickly typing weird Unicode characters. However, these two don’t combine: Sublime Text has an annoying bug which prevents the xim input method, which handles XCompose files, from working.

Luckely someone made a patch. If you'd like know more, you can read about it here: http://whitequark.org/blog/2014/04/14/xcompose-support-in-sublime-text/

If you are just looking to fix the problem you can use the following commands in your terminal (note: this only works with the packages from the official website).

1. First add the repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:whitequark/sublime-imethod-fix
   ```
2. and secondly install the patch

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libsublime-text-3-xim-xcompose
   ```

All credits go to Peter Zotov for making the patch.

Comment: You should add more details and explanation to your answer. Link only answers are not useful if the content to which you are linking  either changes or disappears.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine for me, and it allowed me to close this question at askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/595079/problem-in-sublime-text-3-with-spanish-characters

Answer (score 3):

I was experienced the same problem after upgrade to 14.10. Solved by removing and re-added the keymap **EN_US international with dead keys**. It was automatically changed to **EN_US international AltGr Unicode combining**, that was incorrect.

The baby steps:

1) Click to open top bar right menu, and click the **settings icon**:

[image]

2) In All Settings, click **Region & Language**:

[image]

3) At bottom of the window, in **Input Sources**, click on Add (**+**) button:

[image]

4) In **Add an Input Source**, select **English (United States)**:

[image]

5) Now select **EN_US international with dead keys** and click **Add** button:

[image]

6) Backing to Region & Language, select **EN_US international AltGr Unicode combining** and click remove (**-**) button and close the window.

[image]

If you have the same problem as me, that will solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem changing the “Keyboard Input Method System" to "IBus". You will need restart the computer.

System Settings > Language support > Keyboard Input Method System

Answer (score 1):

Same fix as above, this time for Czech diacritics (unnecessarily complete, but what the hell, I did it by a script xD). Add to **Preferences > Key Bindings - User**.

```
//missing composite characters for Czech alphabet
{ "keys": ["´","A"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Á"}},
{ "keys": ["´","a"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "á"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","C"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Č"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","c"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "č"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","D"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ď"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","d"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ď"}},
{ "keys": ["´","E"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "É"}},
{ "keys": ["´","e"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "é"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","E"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ě"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","e"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ě"}},
{ "keys": ["´","I"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Í"}},
{ "keys": ["´","i"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "í"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","N"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ň"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","n"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ň"}},
{ "keys": ["´","O"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ó"}},
{ "keys": ["´","o"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ó"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","R"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ř"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","r"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ř"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","S"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Š"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","s"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "š"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","T"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ť"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","t"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ť"}},
{ "keys": ["´","U"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ú"}},
{ "keys": ["´","u"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ú"}},
{ "keys": ["´","Y"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ý"}},
{ "keys": ["´","y"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ý"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","Z"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "Ž"}},
{ "keys": ["ˇ","z"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ž"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix to Sublime Text:

Add this to the top of your code:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

or

```
-- coding: utf-8 --
```

Both work.